# Extreme heating issue, Dell Studio notebook

Tags: laptop, cooling, dell-studio

I've got a Dell Studio 1555 that I reformatted recently, and since then the motherboard fan hasn't been working.  I'm using 2 different software to monitor my core temperatures (speccy & speedfan) and both confirm my motherboard temperature is most of the time above 80 degrees Celsius.

Speedfan for some reason isn't able to detect the fan and my BIOS has no option for monitoring it either.  Does anyone know any other way I can monitor my fan speed or fix this problem?

Details: Windows 7 64 bit, BIOS upto date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is coincidental with your re-formatting, and that your fan just died. I would stop using it until you replace the fan. You are going to fry your motherboard otherwise.

You can consider taking apart your laptop enough to expose the fan, and see if it is even working at all, especially on boot, before Windows has any effect.

I also routinely recommend that people use compressed air to blow out their laptop's exhaust ports for their CPU fan...at least monthly could make your laptop last a lot longer.

Comment: thx for replying...wud u know any software that could help me confirm if my fan is working or not, without having to open it up?

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that speedfan wasnt able to detect any fans...it was only displaying temperatures...

Comment: Sorry, missed/forgot that...probably means that it can't be monitored.

Comment: By the way, my known-good laptop also reports no fans.

Comment: :( i guess ill have to take it to someone who can open it up then...

Comment: I have confirmed that only certain types of fans will show...ones with 3 or 4 wires, so they can effectively talk back to the motherboard. I can see a laptop not having those, and to be honest, I can't recall mine having more than two. I have had my laptop for about 5 years, and I have replaced the fan a number of times.

Comment: Also as a note, if it's still in warranty call up Dell and they'll send someone over to fit a new fan in.

Comment: Nope, its not in its warranty period...

Answer (score 0):

Make the Dell diagnostics boot media [using this software](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R239866&SystemID=STUDIO1555&servicetag=&os=WLH&osl=en&deviceid=3841&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=13&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=345369), boot from the CD or thumbdrive and run the diags, it will test the fan, and everything else if you want.

[Diagnostics how to](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xlob/dtg/en/troubles.htm#wp1101057) Scroll down to "Starting the Dell Diagnostics From the Drivers and Utilities Media"

Comment: The one that u linked is for 32 bit...and im not sure if the 64 bit one is there...should i try the 32 bit one then?(Ive got windows 7 64 bit)

Comment: 32bit will work.